# Os.walk wont work with directory acquired through ' match.group(0).encode('string-escape') '

Tags: python, os.walk

I'm using os.walk to search for files in specific directories.

This is testcode that wont do what it should:

```
import os, re

cwd = os.getcwd() 
directory= 'Box II'
dirpattern = re.compile(r'^.*?\\'+directory+'.*?', re.M)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(cwd)):

    if dirpattern.search(root):
        match = dirpattern.search(root)
        match = match.group(0).encode('string-escape')

print match '''OUTPUT = D:\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3'''

for roots, dirss, filess in os.walk(match):
print filess '''OUPUT = gives nothing'''
```

if I type the dirname out in the second loop like this

```
  for roots, dirss, filess in os.walk('D:\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3'):
      print filess
```

I get the right output.

The dirnames have whitespaces.

What I type is exactly what is printed for match out of the first loop. Why doesn't it work?

Is the match.group(0) not a string?

If I do this:

```
import os, re

cwd = os.getcwd() 
directory= 'Box II'
dirpattern = re.compile(r'^.*?\\'+directory+'.*?', re.M)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(cwd)):

    if dirpattern.search(root):
        match = dirpattern.search(root)
        match = match.group(0)
```

and use this function:

```
escape_dict={'\\':r'\\'}

def raw(text):
"""Returns a raw string representation of text"""
 return "".join([escape_dict.get(char,char) for char in text])

match1= raw(match)
print match '''OUTPUT = D:\dir1\dir2\dir3 '''
print match1 '''OUTPUT = D:\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3''' 

for roots, dirss, filess in os.walk('match1'):

    print filess '''OUTPUT= nothing'''
```

os.walk doesnt work either but when I do this:

```
match= 'D:\dir1\dir2\dir3'
match1= raw(match)
print match1 '''OUTPUT= D:\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3'''
```

os.walk works:

```
for roots, dirss, filess in os.walk('match1'):
    print filess '''OUTPUT= [file1,file2,file3]'''
```

What's the difference between match acquired from a regex

```
match = match.group(0)
print match '''OUTPUT = D:\dir1\dir2\dir3 '''
```

and match just written out as a string

```
match = 'D:\dir1\dir2\dir3'
```

Comment: Omg i c why theres no answer, about 5 questions a minute are posted here!!!

Comment: Your spacing is all wrong. Can you correct it as your code could have several meanings.

Comment: Hey Ben can you specify what spacing, i dont see what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You should probably remove `encode('string-escape')` from your code.

Comment: thanks for the answer Amr!
i used encode('string-escape') to make the output of

    print match.group(0) ''' Output= D:\dir1\dir2\dir3 '''

look like 

    print match.group(0).encode('string-escape') ''' OUTPUT= D:\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3 '''

Comment: how can i comment on your answer in the same manner as i posted my question with code etc?

Comment: `encode('string-escape')` is the reason your code fails, because when you later pass match to `os.walk`, it'll be like you did this: `os.walk('D:\\\\dir1\\\\dir2\\\\dir3')`, try removing it and maybe your code will work.

Comment: Ah ok! i edited my question, and threw away the .encode part and used to function to replace \ with \\.
look it up its at the bottom. still the same problem.

Comment: and os.walk wont take this string format


`match= 'D:\dir1\dir2\dir3'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(match)):
    print files '''OUTPUT= nothing'''`

Comment: if you're using the name in your script, something like `match= 'D:\dir1\dir2\dir3'` you should use raw on it in that case `match= r'D:\dir1\dir2\dir3'`, but if you get it from regex for example then use it as it is because the backslashes would be already escaped. google for these keywords: python str repr raw

Comment: ok its just that `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(match):` doesnt give any output when i use match from the `match.group(0)` which should already be D:\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3.

Comment: why are you using `match` as a literal, it should be `os.walk(match)` without quotes because it's a variable, if you use `'match'` it will try looking for a directory named match.

Comment: oops sorry that was a misspeling